# Enabling _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks() in release mode

Tags: c++, visual-c++

`_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()` shows memory leaks in Debug mode, but not in release mode.

How can I enable it in release mode?

Comment: Why would you want to?  Why not release the program in debug mode?

Comment: Debug mode does not optimize code.

Comment: Memory leaks are "tricky" in optimized code. For instance, the compiler may move deallocation around a bit (as it's a known function, the compiler can infer the side effects).

Answer (score 2):

From the online reference:

> Dumps all the memory blocks in the
>   debug heap when a memory leak has
>   occurred (debug version only)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could change the optimizations in debug builds, and have it compile the code as if it was to generate release code, but that might not be of any help. The preprocessor macro `_DEBUG` will still be in effect, so your mileage will vary (depending on what you do when `_DEBUG` is defined).